# Get max date for unique row value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hello I have such data:

```
              campaign  status  d_cap
date                                 
2019-10-07  campaign_1   start    400
2019-10-13  campaign_2   start    400
2019-10-14  campaign_1  change   1000
2019-10-14  campaign_2  change    800
2019-11-10  campaign_1    stop      0
2019-11-12  campaign_2  change   2000
```

Required output:

```
              campaign  status  d_cap
date                                 
2019-11-10  campaign_1    stop      0
2019-11-12  campaign_2  change   2000
```

So I want to get last status and d_cap per unique campaign based on max date. I tried to fix this question by using for loop, but I think it's not the best solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need:

```
group = pdf.groupby(["date", "campaign"]).agg({"status": "last", "d_cap": "last"}).reset_index()
# Get indexes of the max date per group
idx = pdf.groupby(['campaign'])['date'].transform(max) == pdf['date']
# Filter the df
final = pdf[idx]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's not exactly what I want. In your example you are getting max fate across all category (in my example campaign), but what I need to get it's max date per each campaign name. Campaign_1 max date can be different from campaign_2 max date.

Comment: First filter with the max date for every group then.

Comment: Got you. I will edit my answer as such. I will get the max date of each group